# How to regex - get alpha from beginning OR end of alpha string (and numeric)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not overly strong in regex and trying to determine if this is possible...

I have data coming in alphanumeric which could be defined a number of ways:

```
100
NW100
W100
100NW
100W
```

(may not always be W/NW - just an example of letters)

I would like to split the data into variables to hold the alpha and numeric separately. Using regex groups, I have this so far:

```
        var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)");
       
        var startMatch = numAlpha.Match(myDataString);
        var alpha = startMatch.Groups["Alpha"].Value;
        int number = int.Parse(startMatch.Groups["Numeric"].Value);
```

This doesn't work for all cases, particularly when the alpha is at the end (e.g. 100W).

I would like it to check the beginning AND end of the string for the alphabetic part and still store it into the same alpha variable.

I was able to create a third group named Alpha2

```
(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)(?<Alpha2>[a-zA-Z]*)
```

but would like to keep it to two groups (and two variables) if it is possible. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Should there be a match of `'NW'`, considering that there is to be one of `'100'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional construct:

```
(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]+)?(?<Numeric>\d+)(?(Alpha)|(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]+)?)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3CAlpha%3E%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%29%3F%28%3F%3CNumeric%3E%5Cd%2B%29%28%3F%28Alpha%29%7C%28%3F%3CAlpha%3E%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%29%3F%29&i=100%0D%0ANW100%0D%0AW100%0D%0A100NW%0D%0A100W). *Details*:

- `(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]+)?` - an optional group "Alpha" matching one or more ASCII letters
- `(?<Numeric>\d+)` - Group "Numeric" matching one or more digits
- `(?(Alpha)|(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]+)?)` - a conditional: if Group "Alpha" matched, do nothing, else, capture one or more ASCII letters into Group "Alpha".

Comment: Thank you for the lightning fast response! Much appreciated. I will run through testing but seems to be working. Really appreciate the .NET regex demo as I didn't know about it

Answer (score 2):

In .NET you can use an alternation `|` with the same group names:

```
(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)|(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)
```

Note that `[a-zA-Z]*` and `[0-9]*` can both match 0 or more times and so can also match an empty string.

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3cAlpha%3e%5ba-zA-Z%5d*%29%28%3f%3cNumeric%3e%5b0-9%5d*%29%7c%28%3f%3cNumeric%3e%5b0-9%5d*%29%28%3f%3cAlpha%3e%5ba-zA-Z%5d*%29&i=100%0d%0aNW100%0d%0aW100%0d%0a100NW%0d%0a100W)

If you don't want to match empty strings, you can make the quantifier 1 or more times and only have the alphanumerics optional in the second part.

```
(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]+)(?<Numeric>[0-9]+)|(?<Numeric>[0-9]+)(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)
```

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3cAlpha%3e%5ba-zA-Z%5d%2b%29%28%3f%3cNumeric%3e%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%7c%28%3f%3cNumeric%3e%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%28%3f%3cAlpha%3e%5ba-zA-Z%5d*%29&i=100%0d%0aNW100%0d%0aW100%0d%0a100NW%0d%0a100W)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I tested the other answer as it came in first but both answers work. Again, I really appreciate the .NET regex demo as I didn't know about it, as well alternation.